# React Native Navigation Error : The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

here's my problem :
I want to have an image that redirect to a component called "ProgrammationDetail", so I used React Navigation in order to create a Stack Navigator. But I want it to be nested inside a Tab Navigator that I used to get a Bottom Nav Bar. When I press the image it return this error :

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ProgrammationDetail","params":{"programmationId":"3"}} was not handled by any navigator.

And I can't figured out why... It's my first time using React Navigation, it's maybe why

Here's my different code :

```js
//Programmation.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import he from 'he';
import { getProgrammations } from '../lib/utils';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { ProgrammationStackScreen } from './ProgrammationStackScreen';

export default function Programmation({ programmation }) {
    const [programmationData, setProgrammationData] = useState(null);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (programmation && programmation._ID) {
            const fetchProgrammationData = async () => {
                try {
                    const data = await getProgrammations(programmation._ID);
                    setProgrammationData(data);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            };

            fetchProgrammationData();
        }
    }, [programmation]);

    function stripHtmlAndDecode(html) {
        const strippedHtml = html.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
        return he.decode(strippedHtml);
    }

    const handleImagePress = () => {
        console.log("Image pressed");
        console.log("programmation id :", programmation._ID);
        
        navigation.navigate('ProgrammationDetail', {
            programmationId: programmation._ID,
        });
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleImagePress}>
                <Image
                    source={{
                        uri: programmation && programmation.affiches,
                        cache: 'only-if-cached',
                    }}
                    style={styles.postImg}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginTop: 1,
    },
    postImg: {
        width: 92,
        height: 138,
        marginTop: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderRadius: 28,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    }
});
```

```js
//ProgrammationStackScreen.js

import * as React from 'react';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Programmation from '../components/Programmation';
import ProgrammationDetail from '../components/ProgrammationDetail';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export function ProgrammationStackScreen() {
    return (
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Programmation">
                <Stack.Screen name="Programmation" component={Programmation} />
                <Stack.Screen name="ProgrammationDetail" component={ProgrammationDetail} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

```js
//Index.js

import * as React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { HomeScreen } from './HomeScreen';
import { FDSScreen } from './FDSScreen';
import { ProfileScreen } from './ProfileScreen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function MyTabs() {
    return (
            <Tab.Navigator
                screenOptions={{ tabBarActiveTintColor: '#EB5655', tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: '#1c181d' } }} >
                <Tab.Screen
                    name="Accueil"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                    options={{
                        headerShown: false,
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
                        ),
                        tabBarLabel: "",
                        unmountOnBlur: true,
                    }}
                />
                <Tab.Screen
                    name="Feuille de salle"
                    component={FDSScreen}
                    options={{
                        headerShown: false,
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="file-outline" color={color} size={size} />
                        ),
                        tabBarLabel: "",
                    }}
                />
                <Tab.Screen
                    name="Profile"
                    component={ProfileScreen}
                    options={{
                        headerShown: false,
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
                        ),
                        tabBarLabel: "",
                    }}
                />
            </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Did you apply```NavigationContainer``` ?

Comment: Yes absolutely, in my App.js !